# Modal alert but confirm button not reacting to script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a dynamic modal popup alert when a user wants to delete a project from there portfolio.

I am having no issues with the popup itself and getting the ID from the project parsed along with the modal view, but...

The buttons in the modal view is generated from the script, as showed in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmansa/n1vugr5e/), and when I click on the "Delete" button in the modal and wants it to activate a .js function nothing happens???

What am I missing, or is there another way to do this?

js:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){

    var pid = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var pname = $(this).attr("data-name");

    $(".delete-footer").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Regret</button><a href="#" data-id="'+pid+'" class="btn btn-info do_delete">Delete</a>');
    $('#confirm-delete').modal('show');

});

$('.do_delete').click(function(){

    alert("I am here!");

    var pid = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $('#confirm-delete').modal('hide');

});
```

html:

```
<a href="#" class="delete" data-id="23">Delete the project</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete project?</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body delete-body">
                Are you sure you want to delete project?                
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer delete-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Link to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmansa/n1vugr5e/)

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind event this way

```
$(document).on('click', '.do_delete', function(){

    alert("I am here!");

    var pid = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $('#confirm-delete').modal('hide');

});
```

REASON

Because you are adding element dynamically into the document. And the way you were using to bind click event ensures binding to only those elements which are present when the document becomes ready for the first time.

Dynamically added elements doesn't get the binding. We need to use .on() of JQuery for those.

Answer (score 0):

$('.delete').click(function(){

```
var pid = $(this).attr("data-id");
var pname = $(this).attr("data-name");

$(".delete-footer").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Regret</button><a href="#" data-id="'+pid+'" class="btn btn-info do_delete">Delete</a>');
$('#confirm-delete').modal('show');


$('.do_delete').click(function(){

alert("I am here!");

var pid = $(this).attr("data-id");
$('#confirm-delete').modal('hide');
```

});
});